# SQLAlchemy and Postgresql: to_tsquery()

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Does anyone know how to use to_tsquery() function of postgresql in sqlalchemy? I searched a lot in Google, I didn't find anything that I can understand. Please help.

I hope it is available in filter function like this:

```
session.query(TableName).filter(Table.column_name.to_tsquery(search_string)).all()
```

The expected SQL for the above query is something like this:

```
Select column_name
    from table_name t
    where t.column_name @@ to_tsquery(:search_string)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For these type of arbitrary queries, you can embed the sql directly into your query:

```
session.query(TableName).\
    filter("t.column_name @@ to_tsquery(:search_string)").\
    params(search_string=search_string).all()
```

You should also be able to parameterize `t.column_name`, but can't see the docs for that just now.

Comment: my question looks lame now. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The [.op()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html?highlight=op#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Operators.op) method allows you to generate SQL for arbitrary operators.

```
session.query(TableName).filter(
    Table.c.column_name.op('@@')(to_tsquery(search_string))
).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

This may have been added recently but worth adding as a more standard solution.

```
query.filter(Model.attribute.match('your search string'))
```

does it for you as it looks for the right operation available for your dialect.

See the official docs:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#full-text-search

Of course, this assumes the table you are querying is a view built with a `to_tsvector` attribute to apply the `@@` operation to.

Answer (score 2):

My fifty cents in 2021, [following the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#full-text-search)

None of the previous answers mention how to cast the text column as postgres: to_tsvector('english', column). I have a text column indexed as tsvector. And this is the way:

```
select(mytable.c.id).where(
        func.to_tsvector('english', mytable.c.title )\
        .match('somestring', postgresql_regconfig='english')
    )
```

In my case, I didn't want to use `to_tsquery` as ".match" forces. A more intuitive way is to use `websearch_to_tsquery` when you have a search input like stackOverflow. So I did a mix from [jd response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552871/1821558).

I finally applied it as a `.filter()` the following statement:

```
func.to_tsvector('english', Table.column_name)\
    .op('@@')(func.websearch_to_tsquery("string to search",
    postgresql_regconfig='english'))
```

I think this is the general formula and it applies to `to_tsquery` too.

Comment: This did not work for me, I needed to swap the order - matching the PostgreSQL documentation and do this:
func.to_tsvector('english', Table.column_name)
    .op('@@')(func.websearch_to_tsquery(
                    'english', search_term)))